# quartz if method takes longer then repeat interval start when finish

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a job that runs every 2 minutes:

```
org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/2 * * * ?").withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()
```

Currently, if the job takes more than 2 minutes, Quartz waits another 2 minutes to run it again.

How do I start it right away if it took more than the scheduled interval?

I do not want Quartz to create another job and run both concurrently, because in case the job always fails, I don't want to fill the job queue up, I want the job to run with at least a 2 minute interval.

Comment: Use [`withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronScheduleBuilder.html#withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()) instead.

Comment: Will it run concurrently? because this is not the requested behavior, if job always fail ? I want it to to run every 2 minutes again

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @Andreas, done, please read my update, your answer does not seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Misfire instructions tell Quartz what to do when a job runs late.

If a job didn't fire on time because the scheduler was down, or because the previous run took longer than expected, or any other cause, that's a misfire. And you can use misfire instructions like **`withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()`** to tell Quartz what to do.
In this case, you're telling Quartz: "*If this job takes longer than expected, that is my problem, not yours. Don't fire up another instance concurrently, don't wait for it to finish. Ignore it. Do nothing*".

If you want to change this, you can use a different misfire instruction, like **`withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()`**, which will instruct Quartz to fire a misfired job as soon as the previous one finishes.

You can look up available misfire instructions for each type of schedule in [the API Javadoc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronScheduleBuilder.html#withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()).

Comment: Your update is a different question, you should make a new post for it.

Comment: Assuming proper configuration (`threadCount` > 0 etc.), did removing or changing the misfire instruction solve your original problem, about making the scheduler _not_ wait the full 2 minutes to launch a misfired job if the previous one has already finished?

Comment: no, all 3 misfire instructions did not help (using quartz v2.2.3)